# Handling several events in one JButton

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a homework with Celsius to Fahrenheit converter, which asks such things:

1. User should insert the Celsius value, click the “Convert” button and get the Fahrenheit value;
2. User should insert the Fahrenheit value, click the “Convert” button and get the Celsius value;
3. After showing the result for the temperature conversion, if the button “Convert” is clicked-on again, all input-output text-fields in the GUI should be cleared.

However, I have struggled in implementing several actions in one button. Where is my mistake (the code of events in `jButton1ActionPerformed`)?

There is a code in Java, I use **Netbeans 8.1**: as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TConverter extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TConverter
 */
public TConverter() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Celcius");

    jLabel2.setText("Fahrenheit");

    jButton1.setText("Convert");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Reset");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(47, 47, 47)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                .addComponent(jTextField2))
            .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(72, 72, 72)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
}                                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


}                                           

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    float CelciusInput = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
    float FahrenheitInput = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());


    if (!(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()))
    {
        try
        {

        jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf((CelciusInput * 1.8) + 32));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    else if (!(jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()))
    {
        try
        {
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf((FahrenheitInput - 32) * 5 / 9));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    else if (String.valueOf(jTextField2.getText()).equals(String.valueOf(jTextField1.getText())))
    {
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
    }

    else
    {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong type of input",
                "Error dialog message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }






}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TConverter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TConverter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TConverter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TConverter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TConverter().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration    }
```

Comment: I think you should set flags and use `if..else if...else` for considering all the outcomes. For example, `isUserInputCelsius == true` will tell you to call `convertCelToFarenheit()`, `isUserInputCelsius == false` will tell you to do opposite and `isResultShownOnDisplay == ?` will accompany both times to make sure if `true`, then call `clearDisplay()`. Giving you exact code would not help you learn, but All the best! And you are clearly progressing!

Comment: You shouldn't call `Float.parseFloat` without first checking that the `String` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and see if it suits you :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    float CelciusInput;
    float FahrenheitInput;
    if (!(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty())) {
        if (jTextField2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                CelciusInput = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
                jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf((CelciusInput * 1.8) + 32));               
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong type of input",
                        "Error dialog message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                jTextField1.setText("");
                jTextField2.setText("");
                return;                   
            }                           
        } else {
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");                
        }
    } else if (!(jTextField2.getText().isEmpty())) {
        try {
            FahrenheitInput = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
            jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf((FahrenheitInput - 32) * 5 / 9));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong type of input",
                    "Error dialog message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             jTextField1.setText("");
             jTextField2.setText("");             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked!
There is a moment that if I write some value after convertion, Button deletes fields too. Is it possible to add some extra check if the convertion handled or not? How can I add it?

Comment: @Ulvi I don't exactly understand what you mean. With the code I provided, conversion will occur as long as **only one** TextField has a value. If both fields have values (eg after a conversion), the button would clear them.

Comment: OK. But why jTextField1.setText(""); and jTextField2.setText(""); have been added to catch part?

Comment: That was an assumption that when some invalid input is entered, the fields should be cleared/reset. Feel free to remove it

Comment: Also if my code helped you it would be nice if you could upvote it or accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you already found out how to handle events. to performe different actions according to input, you have to check these condidtions (as you already do)...

it would be really helpful to put these into seperate methods

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if (isCelsionSet() && !isFarenheitSet() )
    {
        convertCelsiusToFarenheit();
    }
    else if(!isCelsionSet() && !isFarenheitSet()){
        notifyEmptyFields();
    }
    else if(!isCelsionSet() && isFarenheitSet()){
        convertFarenheitToCelsius();
    }
    else if(isCelsionSet() && isFarenheitSet()){
        clearInput();
    }
}
```

now you can test and verify each method seperate

```
private boolean isCelsionSet(){
    //FIXME rename jTextField1 into celsiusInput
    try{
        Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        return true; //field is indeed properly set
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false; //field is not properly set
    }
}

private void convertFahrenheitToCelsius(){
    //FIXME rename jTextField2 into farenheitInput
    float celsius = getTempInCelsius();
    jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf((celsius * 1.8) + 32));
}
```

if you follow up this road you will easily find your mistake and creat code that is readable and maintainable.

I'm sorry that i don't read all your code, its (hopefully soon no more) messy, right now...

### Note for Testing

once you have made the code changes you can easily create a test:

```
@Test
public void testIsCelsiusEmpty(){
   TConverter tconverter = new TConverter();
   tconverter.celsiusInput.setText("12.3"); //after renaming jTextField1 into celsiusInput
   Assert.assertTrue(tconverter.isCelsionSet());
}
```